# Cycle2: Center Carousel active slide below main slideshow

Tags: jquery, jquery-cycle2

I have a jCycle2 slideshow with pager carousel like [this demo](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/caro-pager.php)

I would like to have the active slide centered under the main carousel, but I have not found a valid solution. I have tried adding data-cycle-carousel-offset="40%" to the carousel, which works great, but then I can not access the final 3 slides of the carousel because of the offset. I have also tried a CSS solution with the same results.

Images attached of desired result.

Current:

[image: Current]

Desired:

[image: Desired]

Thanks!

Comment: You can use the offset option.